# Facing a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Jetty + Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jetty

Hi I am using embedded Jetty 8.x In Eclipse and getting this error, while making simple *Hello* web application with JSP and Servlet. Am I missing some jar in Build Path ?

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

An error occurred at line: -1 in the jsp file: null

Generated servlet error:
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre
Detected OS: Windows XP
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/ashish.s/NewEclipseJuno/JServer/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ant-1.8.3.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/ashish.s/NewEclipseJuno/JServer/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ant-1.8.3.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/ashish.s/My%20Documents/Downloads/ant-1.8.3.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/ashish.s/My%20Documents/Downloads/ant-1.8.3.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Project base dir set to: C:\Documents and Settings\ashish.s\NewEclipseJuno\JServer
    [javac] warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError is more likely a version conflict problem. Can you add your project configuration (Maven ?) to check which dependencies are in conflict.

Comment: check this **[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626692/using-postconstruct-annotation-in-spring-3-0-0-rc1]** it may help you

Comment: Adding Jasper Compiler and Jasper Run time Jar solved the issue but now its giving error after server start i.e unable to compile Jsp

Comment: After if you get some compiler errors then Add tool.jar to classpath it will solve .Thanks Yodamad

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and put some more detail in an answer as I also faced the same issue (or close enough) where the application worked fine when run form eclipse and threw

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.expandClassPath(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;
```

when exported and running form a runable jar.

The soloution (as mentioned in the comments above) was to add `jasper-compiler-*.jar` and `jasper-runtime-*.jar` to the class path in eclipse before exporting (Where the asterixis are version numbers). these I found respectively at: [jasper-compiler.jar](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/versionInfo/1295) and [jasper-runtime.jar](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/versionInfo/878)

If these links are dead at the time of reading then a Google search (or using a service like [jar finder](http://www.jarfinder.com/)) should help you locate the required jars mentioned above.